# Split Arraylist of 2 types when printing it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list composed of Objects
Every object is comprised of 2 different values

```
int number;

String name;

ArrayList<Object> objectList= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

I have another list composed of Cars
Every Car has one value

```
String type;

ArrayList<Cars> carList= new ArrayList<Cars>();
```

I want to print half the `objectList` first then the `carList` then the other half of the objectList

Like so.. for example:

Output= "number + type + name"

Basically i want the second list to be printed in between the first list.I searched the web but i am not really sure what i should be looking for and how exactly to code this.

Again i am sorry for the bad question.. i am trying to learn coding by myself because i can't afford it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the two list have the same length?

Comment: For clarifcation. Do you want something like for example `objectList=[obj1,obj2,obj3,...]` and `carList=[car1,car2,car3,...]` and to print `"obj1.number car1.type obj1.name"` for each?

Comment: `objectList.subList(0, objectList.size() / 2).forEach(System.out::println); carList.forEach(System.out::println); objectList.subList(objectList.size() / 2, objectList.size()).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @Francisco Hey thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes that is the kind of output i am looking for. Also the 2 lists don't have the same length necessarily,

Comment: @shmosel Can you clarify your code here and how it works? I would really appreciate it. I am not sure how to use it as an example.Thanks aswell!

Comment: @shmosel Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @user7 Post a lazy question, get a lazy answer.

Comment: @shmosel Haha. Loved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the first list, and use the index to access the corresponding Object in the second list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++){
   Object obj = objectList.get(i); 
   Car car    = carList.get(i);

  //Print Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to print half of your list first, then you are able to split the original list by half:

```
Streams.of(objectList.sublist(0, length/2), 
           carList, 
           objectList.sublist(length/2, length))
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
.forEach(o -> {
    if (o instanceof YourObject) {
       YourObject o1 = (YourObject)o;
       // Print with YourObject
    } else if (o instanceof Cars) {
       // Print car objects
    }
})
```

Comment: You'll want a flatMap in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily achieve this by a for loop.
But as per your output format

The size of the `objectList` and `carList` must be same for this to work.

Try something like this :

```
for(int i=0;i<objectList.size();i++){
    String name; int number;
    number = objectList.get(i).number;
    name = objectList.get(i).name;
    String type = carList.get(i).type;
    System.out.Println(name+type+number);
}
```

As per your comment, if carList is in another class and is private then, you need to set a getter method that takes an index and returns the `type` 
Like this :

```
public class A{
  private ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList();
........ //some codes
  public String getTypeAtIndex(int i){ return carList.get(i).type;  }
    }
```

Then anywhere you can call

```
A a;
String type = a.getTypeAtIndex(i);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. Is t = i? or is it different?

Comment: Edited it was a mistake

Comment: Hey i think that has to be the answer to my problem but what if the carList arraylist is in another class and private? I am stuck at the "String type = carList.get(i).type;" part. I get a cannot find symbol error on carList.

Comment: If you mark this class private then you can not access it outside by any means. Except as I am about to mention in answer. See edit